# Reading a Global Variable from 2 threads Simultaneously

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

My program has 2 threads and a integer global variable. Assume that the global variable is initialized to some value before thread2 is started its execution. Both threads are reading from that variable. Is any race condition possible?

These functions are executing from 2 threads simultaneously and repetitively in my program.

```
void thread1(int iParam)
{
    if ( gi_Varable == iParam )
    //do something
}

void thread2(int iParam)
{
    if ( gi_Varable == iParam)
        //do something

}
```

Comment: Yes, global variable are thread shared among threads, But you find code buggy if `gi_Varable` modified by some thread, it seems you do not

Comment: Read [Thread can't count, giving wrong result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004993/thread-cant-count-giving-wrong-result/14005004#14005004) To know when there is a race condition and bug when using global variables. And how to resolve by adding concurrency control mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing and trying to manipulate the same data concurrently is race condition.Here both thread are just reading from global variable not trying to manipulate it so there is NO race condition.

Comment: @OlofForshell I have included this in my answer that `reading from global variable not trying to manipulate it`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about POSIX threads then:

> Whatever memory values a thread can see when it calls `pthread_create`
>   can also be seen by a new thread when it starts" ([memory
>   visibility between threads](http://books.google.ru/books?id=_xvnuFzo7q0C&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=memory%20visibility%20between%20threads%20butenhof&source=bl&ots=Km4Q2YXaZb&sig=RDEZI00Px-gwKjh78772WfXRjqs&hl=en&ei=3d7fS8nRPKeXOM6FgfQI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false))

So no race conditions are possible in this situation.

Comment: @skallsp even with two process also for this specific condition there is no need of synchronization.correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: Sorry, cannot comment it since I have little experience working with memory shared between two processes.

Answer (score 1):

The two threads only fetch data, they will not compete with each other.

There still might be a serialization problem, in that when is the global var set?  if before the threads are created, no problem.

If the global var. can change while creating the threads then you might need to serialize the thread and code that changes the global var.  This really depends on the specifics of your application, you just need to consider the possibility.

This is especially true if one thread is changing the variable, and another thread is dispatching new threads that depend on the global var being set to a particular value.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ nowadays share the same approach to thread safety. You have Undefined Behavior if two operations should be sequenced relative to each other, but aren't.

In this case, the write operation precedes the thread creation, which precedes the read operations. This means that the write *happens-before* the reads. No problem.

The reads do not have a sequencing requirement between them. So that's no problem either.