# Thread Concurrency

Tags: c, multithreading

This program mimics the web page counter, counting how many visits to a web page. I just wanna ask what is wrong with this code and why its output is different
the counter value is smaller than the number of visits

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <pthread.h>  

// repeat 100 times to mimic 100 random visits to the page 
#define RPT 100  

//web page visit counter int cnt=0;  
void* counter() {
int cntLocalCopy;
float r;

cntLocalCopy = cnt;

// mimicking the work of the sever in serving the page to the browser
r = rand() % 2000;
usleep(r);

cnt = cntLocalCopy + 1;

}   

int main () {
    int i;
    float r;
    pthread_t tid[RPT];

   // seed the random number sequence
     srand(time(NULL));


for (i=0; i<RPT; i++) {  

    // mimicking the random access to the web page
         r = rand() % 2000; usleep(r);

        // a thread to respond to a connect from a browser
         pthread_create (&tid[i], NULL, &counter, NULL);

    }


// Wait till threads complete.
      for (i=0; i<RPT; i++) {

         pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

    }  

// print out the counter value and the number of mimicked visits
// the 2 values should be the same if the program is written 
// properly

    printf ("cnt=%d, repeat=%d\n", cnt, RPT);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a good idea at all:

```
cntLocalCopy = cnt;
... sleep
cnt = cntLocalCopy + 1;
```

As the old value of `cnt` is read before the sleep, the likelihood of 2 or more threads concurrently reading the old value of `cnt` and then sleeping is very high. Because the `sleep` duration is random, this might even decrement the counter.

Even if you rearranged the code as follows

```
... sleep
cntLocalCopy = cnt;
cnt = cntLocalCopy + 1;
```

or even

```
++cnt;
```

A memory barrier will still be needed, as 2 threads could simultaneously read the *same* old value of `cnt`, they will both increment it to the *same* new value, instead of both incrementing the value serially. Have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14005004/314291) for an example.

Comment: then it needs a read barrier before and write barrier after. and then you also need to consider the fact that + 1 and = are not atomics therefore the value could STILL be incremented by only 1 instead of 2. In the end, you always need either AtomicIncrement or a good old lock.

Answer (score 0):

As StuartLC, you clearly have a concurrency problem with variable cnt.

Perhaps you should use a mutex or semaphore to create a critical region around this variable so that if a thread is editing / reading  in, no thread would be able to write / read  it.